# Do you know dynamical formulas for hydraulic cylinders, motors and pumps?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, simulations, complex-systems, models

I'm looking for dynamic differential equations for hydraulic cylinders, motors and pumps.

I have one differential equation for a hydraulic cylinder, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Assume a hydraulic cylinder pushing a mass $M$:

$$M\ddot{x} = A\dot{p} -B\dot{x} - F$$

Where $A$ is the area of the cylinder, $B$ is the damping and $F$ is the force load. $\dot{p}$ is the dynamic pressure, $\dot{x}$ is the velocity of the hydraulic cylinder,$\ddot{x}$ is the accleration of the hydraulic cylinder  and the differential equation for the pressure can be written as:

$$Q = A\dot{x} +  \frac{V}{\beta}\dot{p} $$

Where $Q$ is the flow in to the hydraulic cylinder and $V$ is the volume of the hydraulic cylinder and $\beta$ is the bulk modulus of the oil. The equation can be written as:

$$\dot{p} = \frac{\beta}{V}Q - \frac{A\beta}{V}\dot{x}$$

So if the hydraulic cylinder is moving, then the pressure would be low. But if the flow $Q$ keeps flowing in but the cylinder velocity $\dot{x}$ is not moving, then pressure $\dot{p}$ increase.

And:

$$M\ddot{x} = A(\frac{\beta}{V}Q - \frac{A\beta}{V}\dot{x}) -B\dot{x} - F$$

But I'm not sure about if this is correct in the reality. So my question for you is if this correct way to build dynamics of a hydraulic cylinder, or do I need to know more information?

Also I wonder if you know some general dynamic equations for pumps and motors?

Comment: general dynamic (constituitive) equations for most machine components and motors, etc. can be found in the mechanical engineering field of automatic control systems and dynamical modeling. See the text by Karnopp and Rosenberg for an introduction.

Comment: @nielsnielsen So do you know the formula for the pump? The static equation is $$Q = D\dot{\theta}$$ where $D$ is the diplacement

Comment: this is for a perfect pump. an imperfect pump will have an efficiency number which multiplies the D(theta dot) term. this efficiency term will in turn contain two parts, one for the bearing losses in the drive system and piston rings and one for fluid losses in the valves and stuff inside the pump.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Yes. This is for a perfect pump, and that is what I'm asking about. But the problem is that this equation is static, not dynamic.

Comment: Can this be a solution for a pump? Assume that we have our mechaincal rotation ODE: $$J\ddot{\theta} = T - B\dot{\theta}$$ and we say that $\theta_1 = \theta$ and $\theta_2 = \dot{\theta}$. $J$ is the intertia and $B$ is the damping of friction. Then we got our state space model:

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\theta_1}\\ 
\dot{\theta_2}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
0 & -\frac{B}{J}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\theta_1\\ 
\theta_2
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
T
\end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
Q
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & D
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\theta_1\\ 
\theta_2
\end{bmatrix}$$